# Python: copying file when destination has this file in use

Tags: python, windows

I need to periodically update Online Excel file on SharePoint. The problem occures when this file is opened by user. In this case I am getting Windows error message as below:

[image]

Is it possible to handle such error in Python script? By handle I mean keep trying to save file after some time by using `time.sleep` function. I have tried with most common approach:

```
import shutil

try:
    shutil.copy2('Track_Changes_Testing.xlsx', destination_on_sharepoint)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

But I only get Windows error message popping out

Comment: If another use has opened and modified the file, do you really want to replace it and thus discard their work? It may need to be flagged for manual resolution.

Comment: The dialog is probably a critical error dialog that can be disabled via `import msvcrt;` `msvcrt.SetErrorMode(msvcrt.SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)`. With this error setting, the write should fail normally and allow Python to raise an exception that your script can handle.

Comment: @ErykSun Users which will open online Excel are not meant to edit it. They should open it periodically to check updates comming from Python script. Your proposal to use ```msvcrt``` silenced Windows error dialog box, but I am still not able to catch exception. Loop (as proposed by Björn B) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `time.sleep()` and a while loop, like you requested. However be aware that this script will run forever if the file does continue to be used. I am not sure if that behavior is intended or would be ideal

```
import shutil 
import time
import sys

while True:
    print("Runned") #debugging
    try:
        shutil.copy2('Track_Changes_Testing.xlsx', destination_on_sharepoint) 
        break
    except (OSError, IOError):
         print("OSError or IOError")
        # wair 5 min before trying again
        time.sleep(300)
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print(f"Error while copying: {e}" )
        # wair 5 min before trying again
        time.sleep(300)
    except: 
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        # wair 5 min before trying again
        time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Loop does not work. Only first iteration is done and then it stops with Windows error message. It seems that "except" does not catch this exception.

Comment: Added some more excepts... try again and report what error do you get?

Comment: Still loop is not functioning and no error comes from print in Python. Maybe some other Python function to copy file will catch this.

Comment: So you get no error and the code executes? Then check if the file got copied?

Comment: Try to add a print directly after the while to see if it executes the loop at all. You can also try `copy` instead of `copy2`